# does retrofit interceptors proceed(request) make real request?

Tags: java, retrofit2

```
fun getTimeOutInterceptor(): Interceptor {

    return Interceptor {
        val request: Request = it.request()
        val response = it.proceed(request)

        try {
            val content: String? = response.body()?.string()
             response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(response.body()?.contentType(), content)).build()
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
//            Toast.makeText( BaseActivity.baseContext , "Time Out :)" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Log.d("RetrofitClientInstance", "TimeOutFRomout")
        }

        response
    }
}
```

1 .I do not understand the following
`proceed(request)` -> does not call HTTP server ,and send request
response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(response.body()?.contentType(), content)).build() -> why he rebuild

2 does multiple `proceed(request)` make it slow
3 how this will handle timeout

Comment: Use `Log.d("RetrofitClientInstance", exception.message)` instead of `Log.d("RetrofitClientInstance", "TimeOutFRomout")`. If it throws an exception, it doesn't that it's always a TimoutException. The exception could be anything.

Comment: `proceed(request)` calls the next interceptor in the chain. Unless this interceptor stops the http call, it'll eventually make the http request. Why do you say it doesn't?